# Prove that $n$ is a power of 2 in the following sets of sums

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ be two distinct sets of positive integers such that the sets of sums $\{a_i+a_j | 1 \leq i < j \leq n \}$ and $\{b_i+b_j | 1 \leq i < j \leq n \}$ are the same, with the same number of repetitions, eventually. Prove that $n$ is a power of $2$.

This problem came from the polynomials unit in a summer course for the IMO. I've been looking around but haven't been able to find any insights. I tried to force polynomials such as $P(x) = (x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$, hoping to find anything that would be helpful but had no luck with these attempts.

Looking at it again, I would think that the part of the question talking about repetitions would relate to the multiplicities of a polynomial. But then I hit a wall and don't know what to do with that information.

Comment: The question would be clear without the word "eventually", but with it in there I'm left confused by what you mean by it. Are you sure it's part of the statement of the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I copied it word for word and was also confused by the "eventually." It could've just been a TA rushing to type the question as there were other typos in the document.

Comment: I had come across this question a while back in the book Putnam and Beyond. I could get a good start (if $a_i + a_j = b_i + b_j$ then $x^{a_i} x^{a_j} = x^{b_i} x^{b_j}$) but could not finish the solution. So I referred to the solution in the book. It is available on internet.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222975/set-of-pairwise-sum-is-the-same help? or https://wild.maths.org/pairwise-puzzler

Comment: This is loosely related to *Sicherman dice*. Some of the references at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherman_dice might be useful.

Comment: It looks like that first link from Gerry had an identical problem. I also looked through the book Putnam and Beyond and found that is was problem 877 in the book. I'll look through both and see how it goes.

Comment: A version of this problem was posed by Leo Moser, Problem E1248, American Math Monthly 64 (1957) 507, with solution by C F Pinzka. For a solution, see Selfridge and Straus, On the determination of numbers by their sums of a fixed order, Pacific J. Math. 8 (1958) 847-856, MR 22 #4657. Some generalizations are discussed, with references to the literature, in Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd ed., Section C5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will just post the solution which I've found on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h2117889p15389742).

Define polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ as follows
$$
A(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{a_i},~B(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{b_i}.
$$

Then, conditions of the problem imply
$$
(A(x))^2-A(x^2)=(B(x))^2-B(x^2),
$$
or
$$
(A(x))^2-(B(x))^2=A(x^2)-B(x^2).
$$
Thus, for $P(x)=A(x)-B(x)$ we have
$$
A(x)+B(x)=\frac{A(x^2)-B(x^2)}{A(x)-B(x)}=\frac{P(x^2)}{P(x)}.
$$
Finally, let $k$ be the multiplicity of the root $x_0=1$ in $P(x)$ (note that $k\geq 1$ since $P(1)=0$). Then, $P(x)=(x-1)^k Q(x)$ for some polynomial $Q(x)$ with $Q(1)\neq 0$. The previous equality can be rewritten as
$$
A(x)+B(x)=\frac{(x^2-1)^kQ(x^2)}{(x-1)^kQ(x)}=(x+1)^k\cdot\frac{Q(x^2)}{Q(x)}.
$$
Plugging $x=1$ gives
$$
2n=A(1)+B(1)=2^k,
$$
so $n=2^{k-1}$ is a power of two, as desired.

Comment: It's interesting whether all powers of two are "achievable" or not. I think that some construction with many symmetries should work (my guess is Thue-Morse sequence, namely, $a_i$ for ones and $b_i$ for zeros, but I'm not sure)

Comment: In one of the mentioned links, ${1,4,6,7},{2,3,5,8}$ fits the criteria, which is interesting because it adds to the question if there is a limit to how many distinct pairs exist for each.